# Is it correct to set $\delta(t) f(t) = \delta(t) f(0)$ within a distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I have some complicated probability distributions which come out as
$$ P(x,t) = \delta(t)G(x,t) + K(x,t),$$
where $G(x,t)$ and $K(x,t)$ are continuous in time.
Is it permissible to simplify such distributions as
$$ P(x,t) = \delta(t) G(x,0) + K(x,t)?$$
Are any properties of $P$ lost in making such a simplification? At a glance it seems normalization and time derivatives are unchanged. The latter since
\begin{align}
 \frac{\partial}{\partial t} P(x,t) &= \delta(t) \frac{\partial}{\partial t} G(x,t) + \delta'(t) G(x,t) + \frac{\partial}{\partial t} K(x,t) \\&= \delta(t) \frac{\partial}{\partial t} G(x,t) - \delta(t) \frac{\partial}{\partial t} G(x,t) + \frac{\partial}{\partial t} K(x,t)\\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial t}K(x,t).\end{align}
Is there anything I could be missing through?

Comment: Is $G$ a continuous function? If $G$ is also properly a distribution, even defining the product requires some renormalization procedure, if it can be done at all.

Comment: $G$ is a continuous function. Yep. Thanks

Comment: You are probably fine so long as you "followed the rules" when you derived that equation. The definition of $\delta$ is $``\int \delta(t) g(t) dt" = g(0)$ for continuous $g$, so as long as the derivation that led to that equation made sense, it won't matter what $G(t,x)$ is for $t \neq 0$ with a $\delta$ in front of it. Continuity of $G$ in $t$ should make that work out, so long as it's also regular enough in space to take the limits that define that expression at $t=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the identity $f(t)\delta(t) = f(0)\delta(t),$ where $f\in C^\infty,$ is valid.

Proof:
For any test function $\phi$ we have
$$
\langle f\delta, \phi \rangle
= \langle \delta, f\phi \rangle
= (f\phi)(0)
= f(0)\phi(0)
= f(0) \langle \delta, \phi \rangle
= \langle f(0)\delta, \phi \rangle
.
$$
Thus, $f\delta=f(0)\delta.$